# How to retrive data stored in a block

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, javascript

I have stored an information on chain and I want to access that information using RPC call.

I used the following code and provided the hash created.

```
const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockHash);
```

How can I retrieve/see the data I uploaded to that block?

If have uploaded "string" in that block. How can i get it back as "string" by providing the block hash

Comment: What do you mean you have uploaded "string" in that block? Have you executed an extrinsic and you want to see the storage? Please add more info.

Comment: "string" is any value stored in the transaction. Consider that i store "abcd" in a trasaction and i have transaction hash and block hash. How can i retrieve data stored using them?

Comment: So, what you have is basically a `system::remark` extrinsic? in that case you can iterate and find the right extrinsic via `signedBlock.block.extrinsics`.

Answer (score 1):

With your instruction

```
const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockHash);
```

You have all the information on the Block, you can get now all the extrinsics from the block

```
signedBlock.block.extrinsics.forEach((ex, index) => {
    console.log("---extrinsic----");
    console.log(ex.toHuman());
});
```

This will print all the extrinsics on the block and the information, you will have to find yours. If you know the pallet of your extrinsic you can filter .

```
const { method: { args, method, section } } = ex;
const pallet = ex.method.section;
```

Or if you know the Extrinsic ID you can filter by the extrinsic ID to get it:

```
const extrinsicId = signedBlock.block.header.number + "-" + index
```

Comment: yes it worked some where closer. I can see the data that  i am looking for and ican extract it